# Saving Turkish unicode characters to SQL Server database and displaying on web page

Tags: sql-server, unicode

I have a SQL Server database with column datatypes set to `NVARCHAR(1024)`. I am doing a series of inserts such as this one:

```
insert into stores (country, city, store_name, address_line_1, address_line_2
              , address_line_3, telephone, website, email) 
values (N'Turkey', N'Adana', N'Adana', N'M1 Alışveriş Merkezi, Yeni Mah. 87071 Sok. No:5'
         , N'', N'', N'0 322 271 01 55', N'www.ebebek.com.tr', N'')
```

On my page which reads and displays this data from the DB, I have this tag:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Its been a while since I've done this type of thing. Shouldn't what I have done be enough to make this work? In the above example, this is what I get on my screen:

```
M1 AlÄ±ÅŸveriÅŸ Merkezi, Yeni Mah. 87071 Sok. No:5
```

I'm not sure which part of my process is going bad. Would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: You don't mention character sets at all in your question, which makes me suspect you need to read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html before proceeding. EDIT: ok, so you did mention character sets, in a bit that wasn't displaying because of HTML tags. Still, what's the database character set, and how are you doing this insert?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't add a comment because i need 50 reputation.
Sometimes the problem lays on the file which displays the text. Set the character set of the file to utf-8 and try it again. Setting the meta tag does not help every time.

Comment: My output page is ASP, and I have also added the following code, which has helped me in the past, but does not seem to be fixing it now:
response.CodePage=65001
response.CharSet="UTF-8"

Comment: That does not matter, if you are on Windows and have Notepad++ installed, open the file and convert the character set in the menu format to UTF-8